# On understanding bitwise in c# Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I spent long time understanding how programmers use the advantage of speedy binary representation of data in C# arrays but I just dont get it.

for example If I have 2 arrays A, and B to store 0/1 data. In normal situation we do like this :

```
    bool flag=true;
    int[] A = new int[10] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
    int[] B = new int[10] { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
    // For comparing the first 5 bits :
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        if (A[i] != B[i])
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        } 
    // Accessing the i*th* positions is :
    A[7]=1;
   int x=B[5];
```

What if I need to repeat this code for thousands of times ? or even the arrays are very large ? the straight answer will be to represent the data as bit packed arrays and apply things like bitwise operations or bitmasking ... etc.

My question is how to switch to the binary world in c# ? for more accurate question, How to rewrite the code above in very efficient way using the binary representation and bit wise operations ? Answer with demo code will be much appreciated.

[UPDATE]
I am looking for an answer that utilizes storing binary data as bytes or bits and uses shifting bits for accessing/comparing the arrays

Comment: Juding by the body and question `tags`, it seems to me you already know the answer to this question.  We're not a code writing service

Comment: if I know the answer then why bothering to ask ?@MickyDuncan

Comment: _[There are already numerous posts that answer their own questions. There's nothing wrong with it. It's even encouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)_.  Go ahead

Comment: Strange, your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576191/modeling-from-c-to-c-sharp-with-bit-shifting) was right along those lines too.  (which I see has been deleted)

Comment: I am struggling in this problem since 3 weeks now @MickyDuncan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a direct translation using [`BitVector32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx)  -

```
var flag = true;
var A = new BitVector32(0x234);
var B = new BitVector32(0x394);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (A[i] != B[i])
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}

A[7] = true;
bool x = B[5];
```

You can also use a [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) if you need mutable size for the array. One important note on `BitArray` is that it is slower - but the optimizations (a packed `int` or `int[]`) are similar.

---

You also have language supported flags enums available - it may fit your use case. Or maybe not. But they are there.

```
[Flags]
enum MyFlags
{
    Foo = 0x0001,
    Bar = 0x0002, 
    Baz = 0x0004, 
    All = Foo | Bar | Baz
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFlags flags = MyFlags.Foo | MyFlags.Baz;
        MyFlags isBar = MyFlags.Bar & flags;

        Console.WriteLine(isBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if my array has to hold 5K elements ?

Comment: my friend, you misunderstood my question, I am not trying to convert an integer number to a sequence of bits. I already have a sequence of bits that I want to apply processing on them like comparing of finding if A is a subset of B or if A agrees with B on all elements until ith position ...etc

Comment: your answer is appreciated but not what I am looking for

Comment: BitArray is very slow when holding large data